# When specific item is selected in listbox on userform, text in another textbox must be copied to table cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a userform with listboxes and textboxes. The listbox contains multiple items but when the particular item "Autre" is selected on one of the listboxes, I want the items selected in the listbox and also the text in the correspoding textbox (which is a description of "Autre") to be copied into the table.

Here is what my code looks like for now:

```
Private Sub cmdSauvegarder_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau1").Range
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = rng.Find(What:="*", _
After:=rng.Cells(1), _
Lookat:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row

        rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
        rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = Me.txtNom.Value
        rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Value = Me.txtPrenom.Value
        rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 4).Value = Me.cboAge.Value
        rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 5).Value = Me.cboGenre.Value
        rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).Value = Me.txtNationalite.Value
        rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 7).Value = Me.txtAdresse.Value
        rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 8).Value = Me.txtTelephone.Value
        rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 9).Value = Me.cboQuartier.Value
        rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 10).Value = Me.cboProfessionnel.Value
        If rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 10).Value = "Autre" Then rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 10).Value = "Autre: " & Me.txtProfessionnel.Value
        rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 11).Value = Me.cboMarital.Value
        If rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 11).Value = "Autre" Then rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 11).Value = "Autre: " & Me.txtMarital.Value

        myVar = ""
        For x = 0 To Me.listDejavenu.ListCount - 1
            If Me.listDejavenu.Selected(x) Then
                If myVar = "" Then
                    myVar = Me.listDejavenu.List(x, 0)
                Else
                    myVar = myVar & ", " & Me.listDejavenu.List(x, 0)
                End If
            End If
            If rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 12).Value = "Autre" Then rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 12).Value = Me.listDejavenu.Value & ": " & Me.txtDejavenu.Value Else: rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 12).Value = myVar

            Next

        myWar = ""
        For y = 0 To Me.ListBesoinExprime.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ListBesoinExprime.Selected(y) Then
                If myWar = "" Then
                      myWar = Me.ListBesoinExprime.List(y, 0)
                Else
                    myWar = myWar & ", " & Me.ListBesoinExprime.List(y, 0)
                End If
            End If
            If rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 13).Value = "Autre" Then rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 13).Value = Me.ListBesoinExprime.Value & ": " & Me.txtBesoinExprime.Value Else: rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 13).Value = myWar

        Next

      myTar = ""
        For Z = 0 To Me.ListDejaSuivi.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ListDejaSuivi.Selected(Z) Then
                If myTar = "" Then
                      myTar = Me.ListDejaSuivi.List(Z, 0)
                Else
                    myTar = myTar & ", " & Me.ListDejaSuivi.List(Z, 0)
                End If
            End If
            If rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 14).Value = "Autre" Then rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 14).Value = Me.ListDejaSuivi.Value & ": " & Me.txtDejaSuivi.Value Else: rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 14).Value = myTar

        Next

     myPar = ""
        For v = 0 To Me.ListRedirigeVers.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ListRedirigeVers.Selected(v) Then
                If myPar = "" Then
                      myPar = Me.ListRedirigeVers.List(v, 0)
                Else
                    myPar = myPar & ", " & Me.ListRedirigeVers.List(v, 0)
                End If
            End If
            If rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 15).Value = "Autre" Then rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 15).Value = Me.ListRedirigeVers.Value & ": " & Me.txtRedirigevers.Value Else: rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 15).Value = myPar

        Next


Call resetform

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you specify exactly what your question is / what is the problem you have currently? This will help us help you. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) as regards my edit (note that requests for "urgent help" will probably go unheeded - a detailed explanation of your problem and what you've tried specifically is more likely to produce an effect, as opposed to a list of requirements and request for code.)

Comment: @BigBen Noted. My problem as i explained is that i have listboxes with multiple items and when the item "Autre" is selected among other items in a listbox (in other words when the selection contains "Autre", i need to copy all the items in the listbox to a table but also the text in the corresponding textbox (which is a description of "Autre".

Comment: @sotirisninis That sounds like more of a need/request than a problem. Are you getting an error message? What have you tried so far? What is the current behavior?

Comment: @dwirony the current behaviour is when I select multiple items in a listbox including the item "Autre", it copies all items to the table as required but the text in the textbox is not copied. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: @dwirony  - If rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 12).Value = "Autre" Then rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 12).Value = Me.listDejavenu.Value & ": " & Me.txtDejavenu.Value Else: rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 12).Value = myVar   --- it is that bit of code that is not working I think